# Составление программ циклической структуры

Tags: java, for

Есть A B C типа Boolean нужно с помощью for перебрать все возможные значения
**A AND (B OR С) и (A AND В) OR (A AND C)**
помогите решить пж.

Comment: С учётом допускаемого дублирования количество вариантов бесконечно велико. Задача нерешаема.

Comment: по идее у логического выражения максимум 2 возможных значения.

Comment: А что именно планируется перебирать в цикле `for`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A AND (B OR С)` и `(A AND В) OR (A AND C)` ->
`A && (B || С)` и `(A && В) || (A && C)`

#### Код:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean a, b, c;

        System.out.println("A AND (B OR С)");
        for (int aa = 0; aa < 2; aa++) {
            for (int bb = 0; bb < 2; bb++) {
                for (int cc = 0; cc < 2; cc++) {
                    a = aa == 1;
                    b = bb == 1;
                    c = cc == 1;
                    if(a && (b || c)) {
                        System.out.println("> A - " + a + " B - " + b + " C - " + c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("A AND (B OR С)");
        for (int aa = 0; aa < 2; aa++) {
            for (int bb = 0; bb < 2; bb++) {
                for (int cc = 0; cc < 2; cc++) {
                    a = aa == 1;
                    b = bb == 1;
                    c = cc == 1;
                    if((a && b) || (a && c)) {
                        System.out.println("> A - " + a + " B - " + b + " C - " + c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Консоль:

```
A AND (B OR С)
> A - true B - false C - true
> A - true B - true C - false
> A - true B - true C - true

A AND (B OR С)
> A - true B - false C - true
> A - true B - true C - false
> A - true B - true C - true
```

Comment: с = сс = 1; это мы говорим, что cc = true ?

Comment: c - boolean , cc - int, я задаю значение таким образом: `c = (cc равно 1?)`, то есть если cc равно 1 то значение `c` будет `true`, инче же - `false`